# Error running Go program

Tags: eclipse, go

i'm trying to run a Go program and it always gives me this error i tried googling it but nothing can't see what's the problem! [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb5vn.png)

```
Executable file (C:/Users!/ABDELLATIF-PC/Desktop/SimpleComputerRemote/Host/bin/server.exe) doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a build issue. Check your bin folder 
Whether program has access to the folder
Check preferences  and missing references for the golang project.

Answer (score 0):

The setup process should be driven by [`Host/install/windows/innosetup-x64.iss`](https://github.com/philproctor/SimpleComputerRemote/blob/master/Host/install/windows/innosetup-x64.iss) for [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php):
You need to check if the setup properly installed the exe, and why it looks for `C:/Users!/...` instead of `C:/Users/...`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the issue, It is no configuration issue or anything. You have to do 3 things as follows,

1) Make sure GOPATH value is different from GOROOT.
2) Make sure GOBIN value is empty.
3) Your package name on the go file in eclipse should be main and not the package name "hello". This should be the case for at least the file that has main function. To do this, File->New go file->Source file type should be -> Command source file-> Empty main function. Then type your code after which you can build to see the the .exe file in GOPATH/bin and the program run.

Worked for me.